# Is it possible to create case feed filters in Napili Communities template

Tags: community, case, feeditem, napili, casefeed

We'd like to hide certain fields from appearing in the community case feed. For example, when the case status changes it posts to the feed. Also, you'll see the note of when the case is created.

[image]

The reason we'd like to do this is to create a cleaner look to the feed. We'd like for customers to only see relevant posts / updates to their case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is controlled by Feed Tracking. Go into Setup:

Customise > Chatter > Feed Tracking

Select the "Case" Object, and you'll see a number of fields enabled for tracking. These are the fields that when updated will show the updates in the feed.

Unfortunately, if you stop the feed tracking it will not only hide the updates from the community feed but also the case feed in your console.

This is a restriction I hit a while back - I have certain updates that I want to appear in the actual support case (that my support agents will be viewing), but hidden from the community case feed.

I bit the bullet and essentially hid everything.

Comment: Hey Rob! Thanks for your response. It looks like nothing is currently selected in Feed tracking, though it is enabled. I think these status changes may be default fields that are included when turned on.

Answer (score 0):

You are testing this as an admin and not as the community user .

You can create a community user from contact and when you view the case ,only feeds  that are posted by agents in the community tab will be visible to the customer

The below screenshot shows the same and hopefully you can test and confirm this as a community user .

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Mohith! Thanks for your response. Our use case is that some of our community users are Company Community users. So when they log into our portal they can see all of the status changes. Do you know if there a way to hide these from them?

Comment: @kevin what type of profile do they have ? If they use community profile then SFDC automatically takes care of it

Comment: Most are using a profile "Company Communities." I'm noticing they can still see the status changes e.g. open to closed, open to in progress, etc.